# Symfony 2.3 FormType getParent()

Tags: php, symfony

I still had a big project running in 2.1, so I finally decided to upgrade. Now I get errors that I can't call getParent on builder instances. Which is right, because getParent, setParent and hasParent methods are deprecated. But what can I do to get those values back?

Comment: This is tricky. Can you show us the form code in play so we could possibly suggest doing it differently?

Comment: @JovanPerovic honestly, I just got this project. It's so big, and I have to replace the getParent on multiple places. Context code is different on each.